install python2.7 on rehl 9 for legacy application
We have an legacy application running on old python version which is python 2.7
i tried installing 2.7 from source but failed to so with many errors
Also tried using sudo dnf install python2.7 but it says
Error: Unable to find a match: python2.7
Is there any correct way to install python2.7 on rehl 9 ?

You can try this approach:
If you cannot find a package for your distribution (and you probably should be able to), you can download a single-file executable "AppImage" containing Python 2.7 and the standard library. Just download the file, make it executable, rename it "python2" or create a symlink of that name pointing to the AppImage file, and put it in /usr/local/bin/, and getmail will happily run with it.
For example, on an x86_64 Linux system, you could:
wget https://github.com/niess/python-appimage/releases/download/python2.7/python2.7.18-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.AppImage
sudo install -m 755 python2.7.18-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.AppImage /usr/local/bin/
sudo ln -sr /usr/local/bin/python2.7.18-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.AppImage /usr/local/bin/python2

Reference:https://pyropus.ca./software/getmail/documentation.html#python3
